# Vim -- detecting ex mode in vimrc

Tags: vim, configuration, text-editor, vi, line-numbers

I have previously asked this in `comp.editors`, but without getting any replies.

This ought to be simple:  I want to configure *vim* to `set number` whenever the editor is in ex mode (to get visible line numbers), but never have that option set in visual mode.  How?

If the solution involves having to start *ex* instead of *vim*, that's fine, but the solution should ideally also cover the case of entering ex mode from visual mode (using <kbd>Q</kbd> in *vim* visual mode, for example).

A solution that also works in *nvi* would be nice, but not necessary.

Comment: If the two editors were in fact *two editors*, then I would be able to configure them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```viml
let &number = mode(1) ==# 'ce'
nnoremap <silent> Q :set number<CR>Q
```

This will set `number` when you run `vim -e` and when you enter `ex` mode with <kbd>Q</kbd>, but it won't clear it when you go back to visual mode.  As far as I can tell there is no way to detect the actual event of switching modes. *shrug*

Comment: This works when switching into ex mode and when starting the editor using e.g. `vim -e` (or just `ex`), as you said. But it doesn't invoke `set nonumber` upon (re-)entering visual mode.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yes, that's what I said above: `number` is not cleared when you switch back to visual.  I have no idea how to detect the switch to visual.

Answer (score -1):

Vim's Autocmd seemed like your best bet, since it has event listeners.  An example would be

```
:autocmd InsertLeave * :set nonumber
:autocmd InsertEnter * :set number
```

which shows/hides line numbers

However, I couldn't find any [events](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-events) for Ex mode when I looked.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a good beginning, but as you say, there's no event for entering ex or visual mode.